# JS error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Tags: jquery-easyui

I use JEasyUI combo box and I have it configured liked this:

```
<input class="easyui-combobox" name="work_groups" id="work_groups"
   data-options="
        url:'pages/get_work_groups.php',
        method:'get',
        valueField:'work_group_id',
        textField:'work_group',
        panelHeight:'auto',
        onLoadSuccess: function(){
          $('#work_groups').combobox('setValue', '1');
        },
        onSelect: function(rec){
          alert("test");
        }

">
```

but because of the alert() I get an error:
[image]

Why I get this error ?

Comment: You're closing the string with the quotation marks around "test",

Comment: Thanks TZHX but why the console display it as parentheses problem ?

Comment: The library probably tries to evaluate the options with something like `eval("{" + dataOptions + "}")` and since the options end in `alert(` you're left with `alert(}`.

Comment: Thanks Juhana, @TZHX post it as answer to select ?

Comment: why people are voting down ??!!

Comment: because this is super simple

Comment: @JurijJazdanov not a good reason !! not all the people here should be professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple. You are closing the string where it should still be going. Quotes mistaken:

```
<input class="easyui-combobox" name="work_groups" id="work_groups"
   data-options="
        url:'pages/get_work_groups.php',
        method:'get',
        valueField:'work_group_id',
        textField:'work_group',
        panelHeight:'auto',
        onLoadSuccess: function(){
          $('#work_groups').combobox('setValue', '1');
        },
        onSelect: function(rec){
          alert('test');
        }

">
```